# What Should Be My hostname and FQDN to Exim4?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, dns, exim

My EXIM4 started to display error after I perform a sudo apt upgrade, now some servers return this message:

```
SMTP error from remote mail server after HELO mycompanyname: 504 5.5.2 : Helo command rejected: need fully-qualified hostname
```

What Should Be My hostname and FQDN?

This is my /etc/host:

```
# Your system has configured 'manage_etc_hosts' as True.
# As a result, if you wish for changes to this file to persist
# then you will need to either
# a.) make changes to the master file in /etc/cloud/templates/hosts.tmpl
# b.) change or remove the value of 'manage_etc_hosts' in
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg or cloud-config from user-data
#
127.0.1.1 MyOldDropletName MyOldDropletName
127.0.0.1 localhost
<internal_ip_to_another_droplet> DropletName
```

An this is my hostname -f:

```
mycompanyname
```

An this is my exim4 config (update-exim4.conf.conf):

```
dc_other_hostnames='OldDropletName; smtp.mycompany.com; smtp; localhost.localdomain; localhost'
```

When i say OldDropletName is because the site is hosted on DigitalOcean and each server (droplet) has a alias_name, and this alias name is the OldDropletName.

Answer (score 0):

`hostname -f` should return [`FQDN`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name), hostname+domain such as *smtp.mycompany.com*.

Put to the `/etc/hostname` your [`FQDN`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) = `smtp.mycompany.com` and make sure that reverse PTR record in DNS returns the same name.

By default `exim` using `$primary_hostname`, you can override this in `remote_smtp:` as

```
remote_smtp:
    driver = smtp
    helo_data = smtp.mycompany.com
```

but it is a bad idea to fake mail server's [`FQDN`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name)

It is normal nowadays to reject connections from email servers that don't know its own [`FQDN`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name).